# Remove user in column B row 1 from AD group in column A row 1

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of users who need to be removed from a somewhat personal AD groups, in the hundreds. It would be very tedious to go through them all one by one and simply removing the AD groups is not an option. My idea was to have a script loop through each row in the list and remove them from the corresponding group over on the next column. Problem is I can't figure out how to make the script go through each row and do as the title says.

I have somewhat of a start, but I'm really not sure how to proceed from here.

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\csvname.csv
foreach ($user in $list) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "groupname" -Members $user.samaccountname -Confirm:$false
}
```

How would I modify the above code for it to be something like:

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity column1.rowN -Member column2.rowN -Confirm:$False
```

Is the better option a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your CSV file has two columns with headers (SamAccountName, GroupName), you can continue using your logic and just reference the second column/property in your command.

```
$list = Import-Csv C:\Users\me\Desktop\csvname.csv
Foreach ($user in $list) {
   Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $user.GroupName -members $user.SamAccountName -Confirm:$false
}
```

This particular code also assumes that each group and member combination exist on a row like the following:

```
SamAccountName,GroupName
user1,group1
user1,group2
user1,group3
user2,group1
user2,group4
```

You will need to alter the code if the schema or data organization of the file changes.